# webpacker: after installation pages in the application began to load for a very long time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I'm installing webpacker to my rails app, and after installation, I noticed that the pages in the application began to load for a very long time, what could happen?

from logs:

`Completed 200 OK in 90075ms (Views: 90072.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

I user ruby 2.5.0, rails 5.2.0, webpacker 3.5.5, node 10.6.0, yarn 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because webpacker is compiling your assets
check a similar question:

[Insane loading time after adding Webpacker to Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038000/insane-loading-time-after-adding-webpacker-to-rails-app)