# Insane loading time after adding Webpacker to Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, time, webpacker

I ran a Ruby on Rail's app, and everything was OK until I installed Webpacker.

Now the loading time is between 180 000ms and 400 000ms, when I try to render any page. Removing the yield cause exacly the same problem.
As I'm using Turbolinks I have a fast loading time when navigating in my app.

I use Ruby 2.6.3, Rails 6.0.0.rc1.

I installed Webpack via webpacker 4.0.7 gem, and Yarn, and then installed React.

I ran `./bin/webpack-dev-server`
then launched `rails server`
.

Unfortunately, I haven't any clue on what to do or search...
This questions is related to this : [webpacker: after installation pages in the application began to load for a very long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295118/webpacker-after-installation-pages-in-the-application-began-to-load-for-a-very/57037203?noredirect=1#comment100603503_57037203), which has no answer

---

EDIT

---

I uninstalled all, deleted old package.json, and reinstalled only Webpack. My app now needs between 30 and 50 sec to load.
I'm wondering, if it's normal that 7 556 736 allocations are loading, related to node_modules folder I guess ?
[image: Print of my console]

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure that, in `config/webpacker.yml`, `compile` is set to `false` in dev?

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: false
```

Otherwise it will compile your assets on demand

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer ! Indeed, it was set to true. But even after the update, my app still need more than 30 sec to update (without React). Updated my question with the matter of "allocations" (Rails 6.0)